# Zabbix - Web scenarios trigger. How to ignore the first failed attempts?

Tags: monitoring, web, zabbix

#### Problem:

> Trigger send an e-mail *immediately* when the site is unreachable.

#### System:

> Linux Debian Stretch, Zabbix 4.2.1.

#### Current configuration of the web scenario:

```
Scenario: 
Name: website.com 
Update interval: 30s 
Attempts: 3 
Agent: Zabbix

Steps: 
(just one) 
Name: website.com 
URL: http://website.com/page.php
Follow redirects: checked 
Timeout: 30s
```

*(rest unchanged)*

#### Current configuration of the trigger:

```
Name: The website.com can't be reached!
Expression: {VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].last(3m)}>0
```

*(rest unchanged)*

#### Explanation

The trigger has to send an e-mail if the site is unreachable for 3 minutes (or 3 last checks with timeout 30 seconds on every check). I was trying to do it in many ways (below*), but with each trigger expression that I tried the e-mail notification was sent immediately when the zabbix detected the problem for the first time (and not for the nth attempt).

```
*
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].sum(#3)}>0
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].last(3m)}<>0
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.rspcode[website.com,website.com].last(0)}#200
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].last(3)}#0
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].sum(#3)}>0
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].last(3)}>0
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].min(1)}>0
```

Please if you give an answer explain it.
Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution/Workaround

I added tags on each trigger and I edited an e-mail actions by adding tag conditions.

For example:

> First send an e-mail action: Can't ping the server.

```
ACTION tab
Conditions:
Tag value server equals icmpping
```

*(rest unchanged)*

> Second send an e-mail action: Can't reach the website.

```
ACTION tab
Conditions:
Tag value server equals web

OPERATIONS tab
Default operation step duration: 3m
Operation details: Steps = 2-2; Step duration = 0
```

*(rest unchanged)*

```
Trigger expression:
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].last()}>0
```

Now Zabbix will send me a message 3 minutes after detecting that the website is down and If the problem will be resolved during these 3 minutes Zabbix won't send an e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Item `web.tyest.fail` [returns the failed step of the scenario](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.2/manual/web_monitoring/items). Given that, you can achieve the desired result like this:

```
{VIRTUALMACHINE:web.test.fail[website.com].min(#3)}>0
```

This will check the last 3 values and alert if they all are above 0 (failures). Consider this scenario:

- All is good and values of 0 come in.
- Site goes down, and a non-zero value arrives. The minimum value over the last 3 values is still 0, no alert.
- Site still down, another non-zero value arrives. The minimum value over the last 3 values is still 0 (there's one 0 left in the last 3 values), no alert.
- Site still down, another non-zero value arrives. The minimum value over the last 3 values is now non-zero, and the trigger will fire.

A few additional notes on the expressions you tried:

- Values `3` and `3m` that you used for function `last()` were ignored.
- Value `1` that you used for function min `min()` means seconds, thus that trigger expression would mostly not work at all.

Comment: Okay, I waited 16h and still the same. So I'll stay with my solution.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I mis-calculated the expression on my head. Updated the answer with the correct one now.